# understanding a real analysis rext

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am not a native english speaker, so may be I missing something in this text. My problem is on the last paragraph of this text, where the book offers the exercise. I couldn't understand: after the definition of the primitive function what is the need to fix $a$ and how differs definition statement from the exercise statement.

Could anybody help me please. Any help would be apricated.

[image]

Comment: I think they’re saying you can replace the “there exists $a \in A$ Such that …” from the original definition with the statement “for all $c \in A$, …”

Comment: thank you @Joe it is it is sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you understand what that means, you have essentially completed the exercise.

What you have is a difference between $f$ and the primitive consisting of a constant, and $\int_a^c f$ is a constant, and since $\int_a^x f=\int_a^c f+\int_c^x$, it is clear that it fulfils this criterion.

Comment: thank you for reply. If I understand properly in some sense it means replacement there exists a in A for all c in A????

Comment: I have no idea what you said in that comment, but it's just asking you to pick up on the fact that $\int_a^b f$ is a constant.

Comment: yes  I got it at least)) Thank you a lot  @Suzu